# MongoDB / Node: Incorrect Arguments

Tags: node.js, mongodb

In NodeJS w/ MongoDB, I sometimes get an error that I can't really trace, but is apparently causing problems for my project. It happens very sporadically, also.

Here's a sample of my usage of a mongo call:

```
savePlayer: (player) ->
    savePlayer = @buildPlayerSaveObject player
    savePlayer.lastLogin = new Date()
    @db.update { identifier: player.identifier }, savePlayer, {upsert: true}, (e) =>
      @game.errorHandler.captureException e if e
```

In pretty much every callback, I have `@game.errorHandler.captureException e if e` just to try to get something, but this error seems to be coming from the MongoDB driver itself.

I've posted a ticket [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/NODE-334) but have gotten no response. On google, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21832923/mongoerror-incorrect-arguments) is literally the only other result for this error, as well, but the OPs solution did not necessarily work for me.

Is there anything I can do to further diagnose this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There has unfortunately been a lot of radio silence from the MongoDB team regarding this issue, but I finally happened upon the reason why this error occurs: there was a problem in one of my mongo callbacks, which was (probably) throwing an exception. It seems Mongo caught the error and threw this non-descript error back at me. For the record, the stack trace for the error (posted in a link in the question as well), is as follows:

```
MongoError: Incorrect arguments
at Object.toError (/home/admin/idlebot/src/modules/idle/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/utils.js:114:11)
at Server.Base._callHandler (/home/admin/idlebot/src/modules/idle/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/base.js:455:65)
at /home/admin/idlebot/src/modules/idle/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:481:18
at [object Object].MongoReply.parseBody (/home/admin/idlebot/src/modules/idle/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/responses/mongo_reply.js:68:5)
at [object Object].<anonymous> (/home/admin/idlebot/src/modules/idle/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:439:20)
at [object Object].emit (events.js:95:17)
at [object Object].<anonymous> (/home/admin/idlebot/src/modules/idle/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:201:13)
at [object Object].emit (events.js:98:17)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/admin/idlebot/src/modules/idle/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection.js:440:22)
at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
at Socket.<anonymous> (_stream_readable.js:764:14)
at Socket.emit (events.js:92:17)
at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:426:10)
at emitReadable (_stream_readable.js:422:5)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:165:9)
at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:127:10)
at TCP.onread (net.js:528:21)
```

So, if you get this and want to spend as little time debugging as possible, check all your Mongo callbacks!